# Getting "cannot call method ... of undefined" error with JavaScript and Mustache

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

I'm using HTML, JavaScript, and jQuery Mobile to make a kind of picture gallery. I'm following the JQM demo at: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/swipe/swipe-page.html
to make the gallery, but it uses a totally different HTML page for each picture. My plan is for the gallery to be dynamic, so I don't have a set number of pages or a set list of picture names, etc, and I thought I might use Mustache to make a picture template, and create the pages dynamically. Here is the basic layout of the code:

In `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    ...
    <script src="mustache-0.7.0-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="mobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script id="test_template" type="text/html">
        <h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>
        <p>{{tempText}}</p>
    </script>
    ...
</head>
...
```

And then in `mobile.js`

```
function showPerson()

{


    var person = 
        {
            firstName: "Feaf",
            lastName:  "McFeaf",
            tempText:  "Hello Feaf"
        };

    var personTemplate = document.getElementById("test_template").innerHTML;

    var html = Mustache.to_html(x, person);

}
```

So it's about as basic as you can get. However, when I run the web app on a local server (in Chrome), and I step through this function, I get an error at the `Mustache.to_html` line, saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'to_html' of undefined
```

I'm fairly new to web development, and brand new to Mustache, so I do not know what could be causing this error. I've tried calling other Mustache methods, like `render`, but the same error appears. Is the `<script src=...>` not enough to have the Mustache library accessible to mobile.js? Anybody have any tips on what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you for any information, and let me know of any other information I should add.

EDIT:

Whoops! Forgot to include the fact that I had mustache in the scripts section, I've edited to reflect this fact. Just to be clear, I DO have (and always have had) mustache included!

Also, I tried the suggestion of @Zorayr of using `console.log(Mustache)`, and it claims that Mustache is undefined, even though I am importing it as noted above. Why might this be?

Comment: I would guess this requires another import script since `Mustache` is undefined

Comment: must be a problem including the Mustache script

Comment: where are you including Mustache?

Comment: That was a mistake, Mustache IS included, I just forgot to put that in the question.

Comment: Can you do Console.log(Mustache)?

Comment: Where did you get your `mustache-0.7.0-min.js` file from?

Comment: It was the file that came with the project files from my work. I'll try using a fresh download of the library.

Comment: I've gotten a copy of the library from Janl's github and tried plugging it into the project. Unfortunately, replacing the     mustache-0.7.0-min.js with the new version somehow completely destroys the templating used in the rest of the project (the html on the rest of the pages is a mess). I tried importing both libraries, and I receive the same error of undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution to the problem, I ended up downloading and using Handlebars. It seems to me that there was some conflict with the Mustache library that was already in the project and the new one I added in. This doesn't really explain why Mustache would be undefined, but that was my workaround.